# Divvy alternatives for linux

Tags: linux, macos, gnome

Does anyone know of a Linux (Gnome, RHEL5) alternative to the app called "Divvy" for Mac OSX?

Specifically, I'm looking for something well-polished and easy to use that can tile, split, move, and reorganize windows based on simple keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: The app in question: http://www.mizage.com/divvy/
The screencast gives a good explanation of what Sirex is looking for.

Comment: Check quicktile, it looks great: https://github.com/ssokolow/quicktile

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check out the grid plugin for Compiz.  I believe this enables divvy-like functionality.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305/tiling-windows-in-gnome

Answer (score 0):

If you like working without overlapping windows, check out the many [tiling window managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager). There has been some [discussion on tiling window managers on this site](https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bwindow-manager%5D+tiling).

Window managers intended for power users, such as [fvwm](http://www.fvwm.org/), [sawfish](http://sawfish.wikia.com/), and several others that I don't know well enough to comment on, can be configured to do all the operations you mention with a keystroke. But they might not fit your definition of “easy to use” unless someone first wrote a divvy emulation package.

Comment: yea, im looking for something polished. I'll look into fvwm and sawfish. Not having much initial success getting them onto RHEL5 though.